# Adding data to a existing data source kendo

Tags: javascript, json, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm in a process of implementing kendo grid with complex json. Everything renderes well but I need to add new Item to the existing datasource.Here is my json

Json

```
    {
        "id": "1",
        "EPF": "1000",
        "Name": "Chinthaka",
        "Components": [
            {   
                "Component": "Back Part",
                "Style": "Style",
                "StyleOperation": "Style Operation",
                "PCS": "30",
                "TotalPCS": "120"
            },
            {   
                "Component": "Back Part",
                "Style": "Style",
                "StyleOperation": "Style Operation",
                "PCS": "130",
                "TotalPCS": "160"
            }

        ]
    }
```

So I need to add a new Componet to the existing component Now I have 3 components and it should display under the same level

{
                    "Component": "Back Part",
                    "Style": "Style",
                    "StyleOperation": "Style Operation",
                    "PCS": "80",
                    "TotalPCS": "10"
                }

If anyone can help me on this that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply push the new component into the array and use your current rendering code.

```
var data = {
    "id": "1",
    "EPF": "1000",
    "Name": "Chinthaka",
    "Components": [
        {   
            "Component": "Back Part",
            "Style": "Style",
            "StyleOperation": "Style Operation",
            "PCS": "30",
            "TotalPCS": "120"
        },
        {   
            "Component": "Back Part",
            "Style": "Style",
            "StyleOperation": "Style Operation",
            "PCS": "130",
            "TotalPCS": "160"
        }

    ]
}

data.Components.push({
    "Component": "Back Part",
    "Style": "Style",
    "StyleOperation": "Style Operation",
    "PCS": "80",
    "TotalPCS": "10"
})
```

Comment: wow man great you are a life savior. Thanks david wow using your answer  I managed to do this  var raw = dataSource.data();
    dataSource.add(raw[0].Components.push({
     "Component": "vvvvv",
     "Style": "Styleqqqq",
     "StyleOperation": "Style Operation",
     "PCS": "8011",
     "TotalPCS": "1011"
    }));

Answer (score 0):

Either do another read to the server with datasource. If you're not reading from the server get the index of currently components and specify the next after it with data you have, do a sync of the datasource component and possibly you'll have to redraw/refresh the component to display the new data.

Comment: Wow Paradox I tried your solution but data rebinding is an issue for me. But simply pushing data to the array worked for me Thanks Paradox I really Appreciate both of you guys giving me this wonderful solutions Thanks Paradox ;-)